# Process message from Webworker created by unreachable code

Tags: javascript, web-worker, postmessage, emscripten

I'm really new with JavaScript, I'm sorry if the answer is obvious.

I want to send a message to the main thread from a web-worker. I don't have any access to the part of the code who create the worker so I can't just add `worker.onmessage = [...]`. I have access to the JavaScript code that is executed at the begining of my process, but not the one who create the workers.

I was wondering if there's a way to do something like `window.onEveryMessageFromAnyWorker = doSomeMagic()`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You need the handle to the web worker in order to listen for its messages. Make sure you really can't change the code that makes the worker, if you you can't read below:

#### Hacky solution

If you're writing userscript or other "hacky" code, I suggest you override the worker constructor:

```
// Execute this before the worker is being created
window.OldWorker = Worker;
window.Worker = function(path) {
    console.log("Worker created: ", path);
    // The original worker is applied on this object
    return new OldWorker(path);
}
```

Note that this is **nasty piece of code**. It might break things.

Once you have this code, you can access the worker that is created:

```
window.Worker = function(path) {
    console.log("Worker created: ", path);
    var worker = new OldWorker(path);
    if(path == "something.js") {
        // do something
        worker.addEventListener("message", (e)=>{console.log("Message:", e.data});
    }
    // The original worker is applied on this object
    return worker;
}
```

Note that you **must** use `worker.addEventListener`. Setting `.onmessage` can cause your callback to be overridden, since there can be only one callback in the `onmessage` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is cool, but seems too hacky for my project. What I really want to do is to send an alert from a worker. Since we can't, I was planning to send a message to the main thread to trigger the alert. Do you know a workaround for sending an alert from a worker? Maybe there's a better on than sending a message to the main thread.

Comment: And while trying your example, JS got into a infinite recursive loop while trying to construct a worker.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you even mean by alert. If it's the `window.alert` then that can only be launched by GUI thread. It would be nice if you provided explanation of your "*I can't access the worker being created*" situation, otherwise I cannot advise you any further. But the whole thing smells of bad design of the project.

Comment: Here's the example of the code running: https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/j0xza3ja/1/ Any infinite loops are not my fault.

Comment: The worker are created by Emscripten when I want to use pthreads. I have a C++ function that let me inject JavaScript code inside of my C++ function. On of these injection is `alert('Something')`. It's working when this part is running from the main thread otherwise it's not working.

Comment: Are you trying to call `alert('Something')` from within your pthreads?